# Why is there so much padding in GIF Encoding/Decoding between blocks

Tags: encoding, hex, decode, gif, animated-gif

I've been working on a custom GIF decoder for a project that I'm working on that requires as little of the GIF data to be stored in RAM as possible (so effectively I pull everything out of the file as I need it, byte by byte).

I've been working from the following tutorial:

http://matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp

with a little help from the specification itself:

https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt

I can do both the non-animating GIF and the traffic light animated example  with my decoder. But when I try to go through a GIF exported from www.piskelapp.com (which uses gif.js as its exporter), I get a lot of padding between different blocks, padding where in some cases there shouldn't be according to the specification.

For example, the following animation https://www.piskelapp.com/p/agxzfnBpc2tlbC1hcHByEwsSBlBpc2tlbBiAgICA_eOjCgw/edit has a beginning that looks like this:

```
47 49 46 38 39 61 20 00 20 00 F7 00 00 00 00 00 4E 4E 4E FF FF 00 00 00 00 00
```

The first 6 bytes should be the header (GIF89a in ASCII) and the next 7 should be the logical screen descriptor (LSD). Given the information here, what should immediately follow is a series of color data matching the number of colors in the LSD. But that's not the case, it's just 3 "00"s, 3 "4E"s, and 2 "FF"s followed by a string of 00s that goes on for 760 bytes. After that 760, I come to a Graphic Control Extension (which is expected, and denoted by a 0x21). This happens between many of the following blocks, with the exception that I'm not seeing extension codes of any kind where I would expect, nor am I seeing image descriptors in the right places (which should start with 2C).

The long and short of it is, am I missing something from the spec? What is all this, what looks like, padding and how can I circumvent it? I've seen other types of this padding in other GIF files using other encoders, and there doesn't seem to be a consistent code for me to look for. The file works in Windows Photos, so there's got to be something I'm missing.

Comment: Could you please provide the target GIF as a file? I\`m not registered at Piskel, so all I can get out of it is a `.piskel` file which is actually a base64-encoded PNG with some accompanying metadata, but not a GIF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is fairly straightforward. The GIF exporter used by Piskel simply has a poor implementation.

It explicitly states in the GIF89a spec:

"The Graphics Interchange Format(sm) as specified here should be considered
complete; any deviation from it should be considered invalid, including but not
limited to, the use of reserved or undefined fields within control or data
blocks, the inclusion of extraneous data within or between blocks, the use of
methods or algorithms not specifically listed as part of the format, etc."

The piece I want to point out is "the inclusion of extraneous data within or between blocks". In this case, the issue is data within blocks, for some reason the exporter Piskel uses always fills the color tables (global and local) with black for all remaining spaces. I realized this after discovering that may decoding implementation was wrong, which was causing issues when hitting the repeated "black" (#000000) color codes.

More information can be found in the spec itself, located here:

https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt